# System.Enum.GetValues: In C# not the same as in VB?

Tags: c#, vb.net

Im trying to convert following line of VB.NET to C#:

```
Dim langs As New List(Of LanguageEnum)(System.Enum.GetValues(GetType(LanguageEnum)))
```

I ended up with the following translation, which does not work:

```
List<LanguageEnum> langs = new List<LanguageEnum>(System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(LanguageEnum)));
```

--> "The best overloaded method match {...} has some invalid arguments."
Even http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/ would give me exactly this translation. What is wrong about it?

Comment: The part which you've cut (`{...}`) would have been the interesting one for us.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to cast it:

```
List<LanguageEnum> langs = new List<LanguageEnum>((LanguageEnum[]) System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(LanguageEnum)));
```

In fact, `Enum.GetValues` [returns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx) an `Array`.

Comment: Ah, I see: VB does here some implicit cast. Thx!